# Add old analysis to NDepend and specify date

Tags: ndepend

I've inherited a legacy project and have been working on improving the code this last year. To see my evolution, I've bought an NDepend license and started using it with success.

But I would like to see how I've been doing since I started refactoring. So I was wondering if you can add an analysis to an NDepend project and date it. I can still get the old DLLs, so I can run the analysis, but NDepend dates it to the date I'm running the analysis, not when it was compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NDepend stores the *historic* analysis result in the directory specified by *Project Properties > Analysis > Historic Analysis results*.

The date is indicated by a hierarchy of folder.

- First level `YYYY_MM`
- Second level `DayOfMonth_Hour_Minute`

For example `$HistoricAnalysisResultDir$\2017_09\12_14_20` means that the analysis result is dated to 12th Sept 2017, 14h20.

You just have to mimic this hierarchy manually and store in it your `.ndar` files (NDepend analysis result files).

A great alternative would be to write a short program base on [NDepend.API](https://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html) to do it for you:

- create a project to analyze assemblies of an older version,
- run the analysis
- create the historic analysis result hierarchy folders
- copy there the analysis result

---

Edit 10Oct2017 Having the historic analysis results available and the baseline set is not enough to update the trends. Have a look at the Power Tool source code using the trend feature, you'll see how to log trend metrics in the past.

[image: NDepend Power Tool Trend]

Comment: FYI: haven't had the time to try this out decently yet. My first attempt failed, but I will try again and let you know, when I find the time.

Comment: Hm, I did what you told me, and also renamed the `.ndar` files (because they also contain a date), but it doesn't seem to work very well. I can choose the "old" analysis as a baseline, but the charts on the dashboard still only have one dot: on the date of today.